# Google Spreadsheet API returning grid limits error

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

I am trying to update a Google Sheet using the Ruby API (that is just a wrapper around the SheetsV4 API)

I am running into the following error

> Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: Range ('MySheet'!AA1) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1000, max columns: 26

I have found references of this problem [on the google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-spreadsheets-api/7fbHUmY3Tt4), however there did not seem to be a solution to the problem other that to use a different method to write to the spreadsheet.

The thing is, I need to copy an existing spreadsheet template, and enter my raw data in various sheets. So far I have been using this code (where `service` is a client of the Ruby SheetsV4 API)

```
def write_table(values, sheet: 'Sheet1', column: 1, row: 1, range: nil, value_input_option: 'RAW')
  google_range = begin
    if range
      "#{sheet}!#{range}"
    elsif column && row
      "#{sheet}!#{integer_to_A1_notation(column)}#{row}"
    end
  end
  value_range_object = ::Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new(
    range: google_range, values: values
  )
  service.update_spreadsheet_value(spreadsheet_id,
    google_range,
    value_range_object,
    value_input_option: value_input_option
  )
end
```

It was working quite well so far, but after adding more data to my extracts, I went over the 26th column, (columns `AA` onwards) and now I am getting the error.

Is there some option to pass to `update_spreadsheet_value` so we can raise this limit ?

Otherwise, what is the other way to write to the spreadsheet using append ?

EDIT - A clear description of my scenario

I have a template Google spreadsheet with 8 sheets(tabs), 4 of which are titled `RAW-XX` and this is where I try to update my data.

At the beginning, those raw tabs only have headers on 30 columns (A1 --> AD1)
My code needs to be able to fill all the cells A2 --> AD42

- (1) for the first time
- (2) and my code needs to be able to re-run again to replace those values by fresh ones, without appending

So basically I was thinking of using `update_spreadsheet_value` rather than `append_xx` because of the requirement (2). But becuase of this bug/limitation (unclear) in the API, this does not work. ALso important to note : I am not actually updating all those 30 columns in one go, but actually in several calls to the `update` method (with up to 10 columns each time)

I've thought that
- Maybe I am missing an option to send to the Google API to allow more than 26 columns in one go ?
- Maybe this is actually an undocumented hard limitation of the `update` API
- Maybe I can resort to deleting existing data + using append

EDIT 2

Suppose I have a template at version 1 with multiple sheets (Note that I am using `=xx` to indicate a formula, and `[empty]` to indicate there is nothing in the cell, and `1` to indicate the raw value "1" was supplied

```
Sheet1 - RAW
RAW Number of foos | RAW Number of Bars |
[empty]            | [empty]            |

Sheet2 - FORMATTED
Number of foos       | Number of Bars
='Sheet1 - RAW'!A2   | ='Sheet1 - RAW'B2
```

Now I call my app "for the first time", this copies the existing template to a new file "generated_spreadsheet" and injects data in the RAW sheet. It turns out at this moment, my app says there is 1 foo and 0 bar

```
Sheet1 - RAW
RAW Number of foos | RAW Number of Bars |
1                  | 0                  |

Sheet2 - FORMATTED
Number of foos       | Number of Bars
='Sheet1 - RAW'!A2   | ='Sheet1 - RAW'!B2
```

Maybe if I call my app later, maybe the template AND the data have changed in between, so I want to REPLACE everything in my "generated_spreadsheet"

The new template has become in between

```
Sheet1 - RAW
RAW Number of foos | RAW Number of Bars |
[empty]            | [empty]            |

Sheet2 - FORMATTED
Number of foos       | Number of Bars     | All items
='Sheet1 - RAW'!A2   | ='Sheet1 - RAW'!B2 | =A2 + B2
```

Suppose now my app says there is still 1 foo and the number of bars went from 0 to 2, I want to update the "generated_spreadsheet" so it looks like

```
Sheet1 - RAW
RAW Number of foos | RAW Number of Bars |
1                  | 3                  |

Sheet2 - FORMATTED
Number of foos       | Number of Bars     | All items
='Sheet1 - RAW'!A2   | ='Sheet1 - RAW'!B2 | =A2 + B2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this because out of range.

AA1 means column is AA, also means 27, so this start point AA1 not exist, that's why you met this error.

you can try Z1, this should be ok.

Answer (score 9):

How about using values.append? In my environment, I also experienced the same situation with you. In order to avoid this issue, I used values.append.

Please modify as follows and try it again.

#### From:

```
service.update_spreadsheet_value(
```

#### To:

```
service.append_spreadsheet_value(
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

If this was not the result you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: From what I understand, append will look for empty rows before adding, but since I am using a template, there may be already some data in there (eg columns with formulas, or sample data...) I will try to see if I can keep the "source sheets" clean and it is easy to append. Otherwise, propably a better solution would involve cleaning the template before and append all the data including the headers ?

(The template is useful because there are other sheets that will format the raw data entered by my backend)

Comment: @Cyril Duchon-Doris I'm sorry for the inconvenience. At first, in order to understand correctly, I would like to confirm about your situation. In your question, at first, the sheet has 1000 rows and the columns from "A" to "Z". For this sheet, when you added a column to "AA" using values.update, such error occurs. You want to add the column without the error. I could understand like this. If I misunderstand your situation, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Sorry, my original post lacked explanation/a clear example. My problem lies in the number of columns rather than the number of lines. I'm trying to replace much fewer than 1k lines, but more than 26 columns in one go, and the 26 column limit is the one causing the crash.
When I open the google spreadsheet template, I see that I have added more than columns already, so the problem seems to really come from the update_spreadsheet_value method, which I need to use since I may need to replace existing data. But I will add a clear example in my post

Comment: @Cyril Duchon-Doris Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your situation? 1. Do you want to copy the template sheet to a sheet in new spreadsheet? 2. What is the difference of "(1)" and "(2)"? What is "for the first time"? Unfortunately, I couldn't see the vision of what you want to do from your additional information yet. I think that this reason is due to my poor English skill. I'm really sorry for this. So can you provide the input and output samples you want? By this, I would like to see the vision you want, and resolve your issue. If you cooperate to resolve the issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Yeah it is also quite confusing, as there is little difference between "spreadsheet" (the file with ALL the tabs) and a "sheet" (a tab in the whole file). Basically by "or the first time", I mean that I am actually calling `service.update_spreadsheet_value` multiple times in my app to fill all the spreadsheet; but then I am calling my app several times, so as to update the same values in the same cells. I will add an concrete example

Comment: @Cyril Duchon-Doris In your situation, you want to overwrite the values of template sheet to the existing cells in a sheet, and the values for overwriting include the outer columns of the existing sheet. Is my understanding correct? By the way, in order to think of the concrete solution of  your situation, can you provide the sample spreadsheet?

Comment: @Cyril Duchon-Doris 1st sample of Edit2 means 2 sheets of a template spreadsheet. 2nd one means new spreadsheet that the 2 sheets of template are copied. 3rd one means the 2 template sheets are updated. Is my understanding correct? What means is 4th one? And can I ask you about your issue from these situations?

Answer (score 2):

```
worksheet.resize(2000)
```

will resize your sheet 2000 rows

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well when I didn't have the empty columns (I removed all the empty columns from the spreadsheet). I simply added an empty one next to my last column and it works.